# Join query results in distinct yet duplicate data in the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, join

I wanted to retrieve the name of the employee from one table and the details of their leave application from another table. The condition that differentiates the employee from his reporting boss is the manager_ID column. The employee_ID is fed as value of manager_ID column for each user. The director has null in this field. Now I have populated this data in a gridview using the below query.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct Employee.emp_name,Leave.leave_ID,Leave.leave_type,Leave.reason,Leave.el_start_date,Leave.el_end_date,Leave.total_days,Leave.status from Employee CROSS JOIN Leave where Employee.manager_ID='" + lbl_empid.Text + "' AND Leave.status='" + lbl_status.Text + "'", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

using (conn)
{
    conn.Open();
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Leave No."] = rdr["leave_ID"].ToString();
        dr["Requested By"] = rdr["emp_name"].ToString();
        dr["Type of Leave"] = rdr["leave_type"].ToString();
        dr["Reason"] = rdr["reason"].ToString();
        dr["Starting"] = rdr["el_start_date"].ToString();
        dr["Ending"] = rdr["el_end_date"].ToString();
        dr["No. of Days"] = rdr["total_days"].ToString();
        dr["Status"] = rdr["status"].ToString();

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dt.AcceptChanges();
    }

    gv_pending_requests.DataSource = dt;
    gv_pending_requests.DataBind();
    conn.Close();
}
```

On debugging, the gridview gets populated without an error. It shows the employees managed by the logged in manager, all right. Only those employees' rows are retrieved and displayed that were required to be. But the data is duplicated in a strange manner. The same row is repeated with a replaced name in the output. I have made a crude imitation of the output I get in my gridview, as I am not allowed to post images. The output shows the data for all the users that have the same manager, by repeating it. While in reality I made these requests from the account of Avneesh only, not ravi:

```
Lv. No.  Employee Name     LeaveType                  Reason           Starting Date
2        Avneesh           Earned, Casual            Personal          17/11/2014   
2        Ravi              Earned, Casual            Personal          17/11/2014 
5        Avneesh           Earned, Half-Pay          Conference        17/11/2014   
5        Ravi              Earned, Half-Pay          Conference        17/11/2014
```

Please point out what I am doing wrong in the query. I have tried using a self join in a subquery, but it shows the error:- {"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'"}. The query is:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct Employee.emp_name,Leave.leave_ID,Leave.leave_type,Leave.reason,Leave.el_start_date,Leave.el_end_date,Leave.total_days,Leave.status from Employee CROSS JOIN Leave where Employee.manager_ID=(select e.emp_ID,m.emp_ID from Employee e INNER JOIN Employee m where e.mgr_ID=m.emp_ID) AND Leave.status='" + lbl_status.Text + "'", conn);
```

Now, how do i solve this duplication? Please help.
I am using Visual studio 2013 and sql server 2014.
Edit: Here are the two tables concerned with this query.

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
[emp_ID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[username] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[emp_name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[password] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[pay_roll_num] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[designation] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[leaves_taken] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[primary_address] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[primary_phone] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[email_ID] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[manager_ID] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (   [username] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF,  
     STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Leave](
[leave_ID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[username] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[reason] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[addrs_onLeave] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[phone_onLeave] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[alternate_email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[leave_type] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[earned_leave] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[el_start_date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[el_end_date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[halfpay_leave] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[hl_start_date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[hl_end_date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[commuted_leave] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[com_startdate] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[com_end_date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[casual_leave] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[cl_start_date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[cl_end_date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[rh_leave] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[rh_start_date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[rh_end_date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[total_days] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[status] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[leave_apply_date] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Leave] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (   [leave_ID] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: First thing to fix is the SQL injection whole - *never* include values directly in your SQL like that; always use parameters. It would also help if you'd format that query onto multiple lines - it's horrible having to scroll horizontally. (I've fixed the indentation of your main code block, but if you could pay more attention to formatting in future, that would help.)

Comment: Your Cross Join Seems to be the issue! Why you are using cross join which gives a cartesian product of two tables?

Comment: You are using cross join which is a cartesian product of two tables. Do you have any reason to apply a cross join? I'm not seing your table structure, but I suppose there should be something like column `EmployeeID` in table `Leaves`. If so the inner join would be a proper solution.

Comment: i think your  cross join is the problem here .. Try to do it with **Inner join**, cross join will make all combinations between two tables!

Comment: As well in your second query you're getting an exception because after an inner join the `on` is expected instead of `where`

Comment: It will be good if you post your DB tables schema.Work on your query with Inner join and then if you face any problem comment it here

Comment: I need the employee name from Employee table in the gridview. I have to store leave details in different table. So I used cross join to extract the data. Username is the primary key in employee and foreign key in leave. Employee ID is used to get the managerial reference.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the CROSS JOIN is the issue.

It is rare to need to CROSS JOIN to a table or query set when that table or query set has multiple rows, thereby creating a cartesian product. On the other hand, I CROSS JOIN to a table or query that has a SINGLE row in it often, but doing so does not increase the number of rows in the result set, and thereby does not duplicate rows.

A good example to conceptualize when to use a CROSS JOIN to a multiple row table or set, is a batch process that needs to post debits and credits (double entry bookkeeping). You can join to a query that contains two rows, one containing 'DEBIT', the other 'CREDIT', and doing so has just doubled all rows in the batch.  One half gets posted as a DEBIT, the other half as a CREDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Thank you all for suggesting to get rid of the cross join. 
Here is the right query, in case anyone else might need it.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct leave_ID,username,leave_type,reason,
 el_start_date,el_end_date,total_days,status from Leave where username IN 
 (select username from Employee where manager_ID='" + lbl_empid.Text + "')
 AND Leave.status='" + lbl_deny.Text + "'", conn);
```